# Brightcove VideoCloud end-users authorization and authentication

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, brightcove, janrain, ott

Using BrightCove VideoCloud platform, how I can authenticate and authorize users to give them access to the content? After looking over the API (http://docs.brightcove.com/en/index.html) I am not sure how to handle that.

It seems to me so far the BrightCove do not have the user concept... Is that correct observation? If so, is it possible integrating BrightCove with other systems like Janrain? What I need is to differentiate between e.g. trial users and users that e.g paid monthly subscription and should have access to all content

Comment: There are several paywall partners listed here: https://www.brightcove.com/en/partners/technology-partners/monetization

Comment: That means in other language we need paying another service and use Brightcove platform only for storing metadata. Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which system you are using, but you could handle the users separately from the Brightcove videos. In this instance you can have two different routes/pages that look very similar. Your controller will send the user to the page with the actual videos if they are a logged in user.

ex:
 `if current_user
    go to page with videos`

If they are not a current user then they would arrive at a page that does not have live content. Perhaps show them a black video player with no content.